# delete space between rows & resize page html

Tags: html, css

I have to create a very simple web page for a blog but i'm not very good with html e css and i'm stack.

How can i remove the space between the rows in the table? See the picture: ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaRk9.png))

I have to remove also the space in the bottom left cell, which has four other cells inside it.

Then i don't know how to resize the page when the window change(for example on mobile phones), any suggestion?

Thanks!!

this is the html & css code:

```css
body {

 background-image: url(E:/Workspace/Sviluppo_Pagine_Internet/Blog/Blog_Images/AGGIUSTATE/UBUNTU.png);
 background-size: 100% 40%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-color: #191970; 
 width: 100%;

}

td {

 padding:0px;

  
    
}

tr{

     

}


table {
     
 
  border-collapse: collapse;

}


.mainTable {

    margin-top: 50%; 
  
}

.image6x6 {

 width: 600px;
 height: 600px;
}

.image3x3 {

 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
}

.td6x6 {

  width: 600px;
      height: 600px;
}

}

.td3x3 {

  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Main_Page.css"/> 

  <title></title>
 </head>

 <body>




    <center><table class="mainTable">
     
     <tr>
          
             <!--PRIMA  CELLA-->

          <td class"td6x6">
            <a href="E:\Workspace\Sviluppo_Pagine_Internet\Blog\BlogPage.html">
            <img src="E:\Workspace\Sviluppo_Pagine_Internet\Blog\Blog_Images\AGGIUSTATE\Blog.png" class="image6x6">
        </a>
         </td>


            <!--SECONDA  CELLA-->

   <td class"td6x6">
           <a href="https://github.com/github" target="GitHub">
            <img src="E:\Workspace\Sviluppo_Pagine_Internet\Blog\Blog_Images\AGGIUSTATE\GitHub.png" class="image6x6">
           </a>
         </td>

       </tr>

  
     <tr>
     
      
             <!--TERZA  CELLA-->           

            <td class"td6x6">


             <table> 
             <tr>
         <td class"td3x3">
                  <a href="mailto:email"> 
                 <img src="E:\Workspace\Sviluppo_Pagine_Internet\Blog\Blog_Images\AGGIUSTATE\Email.png" class="image3x3">
                </a>
            </td>


            <td class"td3x3">
                 <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/linked" target="Linkedin"> 
                 <img src="E:\Workspace\Sviluppo_Pagine_Internet\Blog\Blog_Images\AGGIUSTATE\Linkedin.png" class="image3x3">
                 </a>
            </td>
             </tr>
             
             <tr>
            <td class"td3x3">
                 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/fb" target="Facebook"> 
                 <img src="E:\Workspace\Sviluppo_Pagine_Internet\Blog\Blog_Images\AGGIUSTATE\Facebook.png" class="image3x3">
           </a>
            </td>



            <td class"td3x3">
                 <a href="https://www.instagram.com/dddinst/" target="Instagram"> 
                <img src="E:\Workspace\Sviluppo_Pagine_Internet\Blog\Blog_Images\AGGIUSTATE\Instagram.png" class="image3x3">
                 </a>
            </td>
              </tr> 
             </table>

           </td>


            <!--QUARTA  CELLA-->        


      <td class"td6x6">
           <a href="E:\Workspace\Sviluppo_Pagine_Internet\Blog\ContactPage.html"> 
            <img src="E:\Workspace\Sviluppo_Pagine_Internet\Blog\Blog_Images\AGGIUSTATE\About.png" class="image6x6">
           </a>
         </td>

    
         </tr>

    
     </table></center>


 <div>


</div>




<div style="position: relative; background-color: black; width: 100%; height: 100px; margin-bottom: 0%; margin-top: 3%">

        <h4 style="text-align: center; color: blue; padding-top: 2%">emailaddress</h4>

</div>
```

Comment: Why in the world did you tag this with `amazon-web-services` and `profile`? This is a `html` and `css` question. Please make some sort of effort to know what technologies you are asking about instead of just randomly tagging things.

Comment: This was hilarious! :D

Answer (score 0):

put "vertical-align: bottom" on all of your images.

```
td img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```